# Jquery cookie plugin with FancyBox- format FancyBox

Tags: jquery, cookies, fancybox, format

Me again.

I was able to set cookies for my FancyBox using this bit of code from another question on Stack Overflow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');

if(check_cookie == null){

    $.fancybox('<h2>Some content</h2>', {
        'onComplete' : function() {
                $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
        }
    });
}
});
```

This may be a silly question, but now my problem is that I've lost the formatting for my FancyBox. Can someone please tell me where I should put this code so that I can have my cookies and formatting?

```
{
   'autoDimensions'    : false,
   'width'             : 450,
   'height'            : 190,
   'transitionIn'      : 'none',
   'transitionOut'     : 'none'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');

if(check_cookie == null){

    $.fancybox('<h2>Some content</h2>', {
        'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'             : 450,
        'height'            : 190,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'onComplete' : function() {
                $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
        }
    });
}
});
```